# Passing a giant xml parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

the create script for the stored procedure is as follows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedprocedure] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Mappings XML
AS
BEGIN
 ......
END
```

And I invoke it with

```
exec storedprocedure xmlparam.
```

The issue is that xmlparam is huge and each time I run the 'exec stored procedure xmlparam', sql server management studio freezes up for several minutes.

Is there a better way of doing this? I want to run the exec command through ssms as I wanna see the different record sets it spits out.

Comment: I mentioned sql server management studio in the question and ssms in the tag which is short for sql server management studio. I'll add it in the title as well so non microsoft people dont get confused.

Comment: I already added a **tag** - that's where this info belongs (not in the title). Also: which **version** of SQL Server? 2005? 2008? 2008 R2? 2012?